# Posts to Database stops working after several posts

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I'm building an app using MEAN stack. I have a list of golfers that can be selected via a click event. Once the user clicks a golfer, the golfer is pushed to that users picks array.
 The functionality works for the first 5 or 6 chosen players from the list, then the backend stops responding to any future selections. The UI continues to work as expected.

1. Does anyone know what the problem could be?
2. Is there a better way to structure my app?

golfers.component.ts

```
 draftGolfer(g) { 
 // front end logic
 this.postGolfer(g, this.users[i])
}
 postGolfer(golfer, user){
  this.post.postToDB(golfer, user).subscribe(data => {
   console.log(data)
  });
}
```

post-service.ts

```
postToDB(golfer, user){
let payload = {
  user: user,
  golfer: golfer
}   

return this.http.post("http://localhost:3010/post", payload)
.pipe(
  tap(_ => this.log()),
  catchError(this.handleError('addGolferUser'))
 )
}
```

posts.js

```
router.post("", (req, res) => {

Register.findOneAndUpdate({username: req.body["user"]["username"]},
{$push: {picks: req.body["golfer"]}},
  function (error, success) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("ERRRORRRR");
        } else {

            console.log(`success: ${req.body.golfer.Name}`);
        }
    });
})
```

Model.js

```
const registerSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type: String},
    password: {type: String},
    picks: [],
    active: {type: Boolean}
});
```

Comment: Does postman give you the same behavior, i.e. post failed after 6-ish players? Or the first 6-ish players have something special?